# iframe didnt popup warning for untrusted certificate

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, https

I have an iframe and inside that I am trying to access https url ,Ip address of webpage (https as well) and iframe url are same but port number are different.I am using firefox, for chrome this works fine.FF version is 32

Now I searched and people recommended to use 
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups" still I am not getting pop-up warning , which will allow user to confirm security exception and proceed , Instead I get

IP:Port uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided. (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

Please help , i want a popup so that user can confirm and proceed

Comment: I have the same error in an APK generated from cordova, did you get any solution? maybe a pollyfill?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from mozilla community so look like it is as per design
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1028394#answer-647387

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, you need to open the child page. A window to confirm the untrusted certificate opens, confirm it. Then you can open the parent page.

I encountered it while using CORS request to different domain with untrusted certificate, I believe it behaves in the same way.